# Redirecting PostgreSQL Notices to a Bash Array

Tags: bash, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL statement which raises notices. I wish to redirect this output into a bash array. I have tried the following:

```
declare -a MYARRAY
MYARRAY=( `psql -U $db_username -h $DATABASE_HOST $DATABASE_NAME -c \
"DO \\$\\$ DECLARE
mySite varchar;
myResult RECORD;

BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'current_site, folder, path'; 
    FOR mySite IN SELECT name from public.app_info
    LOOP
        {Confidential Data here!}
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE '%,%,%', myResult.current_site, myResult.folder, myResult.path;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END\\$\\$"` )

echo "These are the files"
for i in ${MYARRAY[@]}; do
        echo $i
done
```

When I run my script my notices from the query are printed to my window but they are not added into the array. I have also tried this with a variable instead of an array, with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notices are printed into stderr so change 
`` END\\$\\$"` ) `` to `` END\\$\\$" 2>&1` ) ``
but array will contain also texts like NOTICE: and DO so you have to filter them out

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.